# Simple High-Low game in Ruby

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm trying to write a simple  high-low program that will output  like this:

```
$ ./highlow.rb 
Please tell me the max value of the random number: 100
Ok. The random number is generated between 1 and 100.  
Make your guess: 50
That's too low.  Guess again: 75
That's too high.  Guess again: 63
That's too low.  Guess again: 68
Correct!  You guessed the answer in 4 tries!
Would you like to play again? no
OK. Goodbye.
$
```

This is the code I have, but I'm going wrong somewhere. It appears to work sometimes:

```
count=0
play = true
while play = true
```

```
print "Please tell me the max value of the random number: "
    max= gets.to_i
    num= rand(max)
puts "Ok. The random number is generated between 1 and " + max.to_s + 
"."
print "Make your guess: "
    guess=gets.to_i

    while guess != num && play != false 
        if guess > num
            print "That's too high. Guess again: "
            guess=gets.to_i
            count+=1
        end

        if guess < num
            print "That's too low. Guess again: "
            guess=gets.to_i
            count+=1
        else
            break
        end
end
```

puts "Correct!  You guessed the answer in " + count.to_s + " tries!"
print "Would you like to play again? "

answer=gets.chomp!
    if answer  == 'n'
        play = false
        break
    end

```
if 
    answer == 'y'
    play = true
end
```

end
puts "OK. Goodbye"

Any suggestions? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What **happens** when it does not work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem (the one I can see anyway) is with number checking code.

If `guess` is greater than `num`, then the first if statement will execute, but then the second one will redirect to the else, breaking out of the loop.

You need to use an `elsif`. Try changing it to this:

```
    if guess > num
        print "That's too high. Guess again: "
        guess=gets.to_i
        count+=1
    elsif guess < num
        print "That's too low. Guess again: "
        guess=gets.to_i
        count+=1
    else
        break
    end
```

Comment: There's one other issue too: if the user guesses properly the very first try, `count` remains 0.

Comment: Minor nitpick on OP's code: the random number will never be 100. However, it can be zero.